# Codeigniter routing the proper way

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to understand how codeigniter routing works.

i know that codeigniter interprets url as www.example.com/class/function/id. I have defined this url below but it returns me to the page where I am currently at. say am at about.php page , it returns me to the same page

`$route['webadmin/teacher/class/subject/(:num)/(:num)'] = "admin/teacher_details/$1/$2";`

in my admin controller i have defined teacher_details as

`public function teacher_details($a='', $b = '', $c ''){}`

what i want is for the defined url to render as www.example.com/webadmin/teacher/class/subject/id1/id2 for the controller admin/teacher_details

Answer (score 0):

codeigniter support segment based url, not query like 
in we pass url as domain/controller/funtion_name/parameter.
suppose you have created a controller named demo with function demo_function

```html
class Demo extends CI_Controller
{
  public function demo_function($id='')
  {
    echo "demo"
  }
}
```

```html
then you will create route in config/route.php
$route['demo/(:num)'] = 'demo/demo_function';
you can access parameter of url like $this->url->segment(3)
or $this->input->get('parament_name');
```